# Error 1064 in a procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, select-into

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= (se
lect ifnull(max(manufactureId+1),1) from tbl_Manufacturer
                ) ;
```

```
create procedure ManufactureAdd(
    p_manufactureName longtext,
    p_address longtext,
    p_phone varchar(50),
    p_email varchar(50),
    p_description longtext
)
begin
    declare p_manufactureId = (select ifnull(max(manufactureId+1),1) from tbl_Manufacturer
    ) ;

    insert into tbl_Manufacturer(
        manufactureId,   
 manufactureName,   
 address,   
 phone,   
 email,   
 description  
)  
VALUES      
(  
 p_manufactureId,   
 p_manufactureName,   
 p_address,   
 p_phone,   
 p_email,   
 p_description  
)  ;

SELECT p_manufactureId  ;

end
```

Comment: The code referred to in your error message doesn't appear in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use SELECT..INTO clause and simple user variable -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ManufactureAdd(
  p_manufactureName longtext,
  p_address longtext,
  p_phone varchar(50),
  p_email varchar(50),
  p_description longtext)
BEGIN
  SELECT IFNULL(MAX(manufactureId + 1), 1) INTO @p_manufactureId FROM tbl_Manufacturer;

  INSERT INTO tbl_Manufacturer (manufactureId, manufactureName, address, phone, email, DESCRIPTION)
    VALUES (@p_manufactureId, p_manufactureName, p_address, p_phone, p_email, p_description);

  SELECT @p_manufactureId;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ManufactureAdd(
    p_manufactureName LONGTEXT,
    p_address LONGTEXT,
    p_phone VARCHAR(50),
    p_email VARCHAR(50),
    p_description LONGTEXT
)
BEGIN
   DECLARE p_manufactureId INT;
   SELECT IFNULL(MAX(manufactureId+1),1) INTO p_manufactureId FROM tbl_Manufacturer;

   INSERT INTO tbl_Manufacturer(
        manufactureId, manufactureName, address, phone, email, description  
    )  
    VALUES (  
        p_manufactureId, p_manufactureName, p_address, p_phone, p_email, p_description  
    );

    SELECT p_manufactureId ;
END
```